# Move lots of files from a directory structure to another in linux (mavenify a java project)

Tags: linux, sed, find

I have a big java project with multiple modules, files of the project are each in `module1`, `module2` ... folders. Now I want to restructure the directories to maven/gradle friendly mode, so all .java files be in `MODULE_NAME\src\main\java\` and all non-java files be in `MODULE_NAME\src\main\resources\` folders.

```
cd /home/MYUSER/oldproject
find . -type f -name *.java -print | exec `sed 's:^./\([a-z0-9\-]*\)/\(.*\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*.java\):mkdir -p /home/MYUSER/project/\1/src/main/java/\2:'`
```

this command creates required folders (packages) well, but when execute

```
find . -type f -name *.java -print | exec `sed 's:^./\([a-z0-9\-]*\)/\(.*\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*.java\):mv \0 /home/MYUSER/project/\1/src/main/java/\2/:'`
```

I get lots of errors with messages:

```
mv: cannot stat 'mv': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/home/MYUSER/project/module1/src/main/java/com/apackage/': No such file or directory
```

when package exists, and many of my files are just moved to a module which is irrelevant.

Can someone help me with the problem.

---

To make it more clear in `s:^./\([a-z0-9\-]*\)/\(.*\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*.java\)` regular expression, first capture (`\([a-z0-9\-]*\)`) gets module, 2nd capture (`\(.*\)`) gets java package and 3rd one (`\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*.java\)`) gets the class name.

---

Sample list of files:

```
./oldproject/module1/com/mycompany/dir1/dir2/dir3/Class1.java
./oldproject/module1/com/mycompany/dir1/dir4/Class2.java
./oldproject/module2/com/mycompany/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/Class3.java
./oldproject/module2/com/mycompany/dir5/dir6/File1.txt
./oldproject/module2/META-INF/File2.txt
```

I want them to become

```
./project/module1/src/main/java/com/mycompany/dir1/dir2/dir3/Class1.java
./project/module1/src/main/java/com/mycompany/dir1/dir4/Class2.java
./project/module2/src/main/java/com/mycompany/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/Class3.java
./project/module2/src/main/resources/com/mycompany/dir5/dir6/File1.txt
./project/module2/src/main/resources/META-INF/File2.txt
```

modules names regular expression `\([a-z0-9\-]*\)`
package names (intermediate folders) regular expression `\([a-z0-9_]*\)` (but can be multiple nested packages)
class names regular expression `\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*.java\)`

---

Update:
It seems my `sed` which produces `mv` command concat all command and that's the problem (there is not a new line between them), so seems the exec does not execute output of each sed one by one. So the question is how did mkdir work?

Comment: Using `find`, for `*.java*` you need quotes: `'*java*'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd /home/MYUSER/
shopt -s globstar # required in bash for recursion, not needed by zsh
for f in **/*.java; do
    nf=$(sed 's:^oldproject/\([a-z0-9\-]*\)/\(.*\)/\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*.java\):project/\1/src/main/java/\2/\3:' <<< "$f")
    echo install -D "$f" "$nf"
    echo rm -f "$f"
done

# clean empty dirs
#find . -type d -exec rmdir {} + 2>/dev/null
#rm -rf oldproject # or this one if it's what you need
```

Drop the two `echo` commands if attempts are satisfactory.

The `install -D source_file dest_file` create the whole directory structure needed, as `mkdir -p` does, transparently.

### Output

```
install -D oldproject/module1/com/mycompany/dir1/dir2/dir3/Class1.java project/module1/src/main/java/com/mycompany/dir1/dir2/dir3/Class1.java
rm -f oldproject/module1/com/mycompany/dir1/dir2/dir3/Class1.java
install -D oldproject/module1/com/mycompany/dir1/dir4/Class2.java project/module1/src/main/java/com/mycompany/dir1/dir4/Class2.java
rm -f oldproject/module1/com/mycompany/dir1/dir4/Class2.java
install -D oldproject/module2/com/mycompany/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/Class3.java project/module2/src/main/java/com/mycompany/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/Class3.java
rm -f oldproject/module2/com/mycompany/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/Class3.java
```

Comment: a `/` is needed between `\2\3`, should become `\2/\3`. besides that, it's prefect

Comment: now the 2nd part is moving non java files to another folder, I tried the same by `for * in **/*.*` iterate directories too, I just want files.

Comment: If you have new needs that not appears in original question, then ask a new one